# What is xsession-errors?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

So I was looking into why a program was getting rid of my background, and the author of the program said to post .xsession-errors and many people did. Then my next question was: What is .xsession-errors? A google search reveals many results but nothing explaining what it is.

What I know so far:

- It's some kind of error log. I can't figure out what it's related too (ubuntu itself? programs?)
- I have one and it seems like all Ubuntu systems have it, though I cannot verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the error log produced by your X windows system (which the Ubuntu GUI is built on top of).

Basically it's quite a low level error log for X11.

Comment: Quick question. I just looked through the `.xsession-errors` file, and there are SO many errors. However, my desktop works seemingly fine. Should I be worried about any of these errors?

Comment: @Rohan No way to know without seeing the errors. Suggest you ask a new question and include some of the issues.

Answer (score 17):

Linux graphical interfaces (such as GNOME) provide a way to run applications by clicking on icons instead of running them manually on the command-line.  However, by doing so, output from the command-line is lost - especially the error output (STDERR).

To deal with this, some display managers (such as GDM) pipe the error output to ~/.xsession-errors, which can then be used for debugging purposes.  Note that since all applications launched this way dump to the same log, it can get quite large and difficult to find specific messages.

**Update:** Per [the documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-debug.html.en):

> The ~/.xsession-errors X session log file has been deprecated and is
> no longer used.

It has been replaced by the systemd journal (`journalctl` command).

Comment: On particular app quickly filled up my hard drive 100MB with this one log file.  I need to find a way to  limit it.

Comment: Does it also capture STDOUT, or is only STDERR?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Depends on the display manager. You can have a quick look at yours, since it is usually (I think) a shell script that does that.